# Json Serialization causes a Stack OverFlow Error in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, json, stack-overflow

Im trying to serialize a shape in Silverlight 4 using Newtonsofts Json serializer. The problem is as soon as I try serialize ANY object, my program breaks and I get the error

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.dll"

I really don't want to use the .Net one as its overly complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: lol - overly complicated how?   var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TRequest));
                    serializer.WriteObject(ms, resource);